# Multiple cases in Oracle sql. Getting the following error

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm getting 00923. 00000 "FROM keyword not found where expected" error while using case. can you help me with multiple cases. How to use them and how to resolve below case

```
SELECT WorkflowHistory.*,
  Reason.Reason,
  ApprovalType.ApprovalType
  CASE
    WHEN NVL(APPROVALTYPE,'')=''
    THEN 'APPROVALTYPE'      = XPURPOSEFORREJECTION
  END
  CASE
    WHEN NVL(daction,'')='sendTo'
    THEN 'daction'      = 'Approve'
  END
FROM WorkflowHistory WorkflowHistory,
  Reason Reason,
  ApprovalType ApprovalType
WHERE UPPER(dDocName)     = UPPER('D_1238777')
AND xPurposeForSubmission = Reason.ReasonID(+)
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add commas to separate your case expressions, and add optional field names. The assignment syntax needs to be changed like this:

```
SELECT WorkflowHistory.*,
  Reason.Reason,
  ApprovalType.ApprovalType
  CASE
    WHEN APPROVALTYPE IS NULL
    THEN XPURPOSEFORREJECTION
  END AS APPROVALTYPE,
  CASE
    WHEN NVL(daction,'')='sendTo'
    THEN 'Approve'
  END AS daction
FROM WorkflowHistory WorkflowHistory,
  Reason Reason,
  ApprovalType ApprovalType
WHERE UPPER(dDocName)     = UPPER('D_1238777')
AND xPurposeForSubmission = Reason.ReasonID(+)
```

Your query appears to be missing join criteria for the `ApprovalType` table. Also consider switching to ANSI joins from Oracle-specific `(+)` syntax.

Comment: I also doubt that part after THEN `'APPROVALTYPE'      = XPURPOSEFORREJECTION` uses correct syntax.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin You are right, I missed that part. I made a guess at what the OP meant by the assignments (although it could be that he meant it the other way around). Thanks!

Comment: `NVL(APPROVALTYPE,'') = ''` will never be true since empty string in Oracle evaluates to NULL, and neither of `NULL = ''` nor `NULL = NULL` is true.

Comment: @Ronnis You are right, I forgot that `''`s in Oracle are treated as `NULL`s (haven't been working with their databases for more than a decade). Thanks for the correction!